# Adding Google's protocol Buffer to Qt ; Disable Compiler Warnings

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, protocol-buffers, compiler-warnings

In order to add the protobuf library from google to my Qt Project I did the following steps. I use `Windows 10` and `Qt 5.6` with the `mingw32`compiler.

## 1 Install protobuf

Therefore I installed MSYS with mingw and `cd` to the `protobuf-3.0.0-beta-2` directory where I ran the configure script `./configure --prefix= 'cd /c/qt/Tools/mingw492_32/ ; pwd -W`  making sure to install protobuf in the Qt compiler directory. Afterwards I ran `make`and `make install`.

## 2 Compile Project with protobuf

Now I add the include path `INCLUDEPATH += C:/qt/tools/mingw492_32/include`and the library path `LIBS += $$PWD/../protobuf-3.0.0-beta-2/src/libs/libprotobuf.a` to my Qt project files to make the google protobuf available.

Compiling my project works but I receive a lot of warnings since the protobuf library has a lot of unused parameters / dummy functions. Is there any way to turn of the warnings obtained from the external protobuf library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that the protobuf headers are system headers. The `-I` flag tells the compiler where to look for non-system headers, whereas `-isystem` gives directories containing system headers. System headers do not produce warnings. But `INCLUDEPATH` uses `-I`.

Instead of:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/qt/tools/mingw492_32/include
```

Try:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem C:/qt/tools/mingw492_32/include
```